# JavaScript - Chrome - RegEx Pattern Replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I'm working with some JavaScript regex values, and I'm running into some problems. The variable startVals holds a string in the format: x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3; The below pattern should match each of the values, and indeed it does in all browsers except for Chrome. In Chrome, each value returns the value of the first pattern ($1). So if the value was 10,10;20,20;30,30; Chrome would return the value of 10 for all groups $1 through $6. Any idea what's causing this?

```
var pattern = /(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);/i;
leftSlider.end.x = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$1"));
leftSlider.end.y = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$2"));
rightSlider.end.x = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$3"));
rightSlider.end.y = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$4"));
topSlider.end.x = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$5"));
topSlider.end.y = parseInt(startVals.replace(pattern,"$6"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to do this is

```
var match = startVals.match(/^(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);$/)

leftSlider.end.x = +match[1];
leftSlider.end.y = +match[2];
rightSlider.end.x = +match[3];
rightSlider.end.y = +match[4];
topSlider.end.x = +match[5];
topSlider.end.y = +match[6];
```

which works in Chrome.

In Chrome,

```
"10,10;20,20;30,30;".match(/^(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);$/)
```

yields

```
["10,10;20,20;30,30","10","10","20","20","30","30"]
```

Comment: You're right, I had a typo in the info above. It should have been 10,10;20,20;30,30;.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens, but you could try this if that's all the string contains:

```
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var matches = pattern.exec(startVals);

leftSlider.end.x = parseInt(matches[0], 10);
leftSlider.end.y = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
rightSlider.end.x = parseInt(matches[2], 10);
rightSlider.end.y = parseInt(matches[3], 10);
topSlider.end.x = parseInt(matches[4], 10);
topSlider.end.y = parseInt(matches[5], 10);
```

Also, don't apply the case-insensitive flag to a regular expression like that involving only digits and punctuation, it will slow it down. Also don't perform that many replacements in that way.

Comment: I do not see how this works.  I run it in this jsFiddle in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/T3waJ/ and get only one match, not 6.

Comment: @jfriend00: Oops, it was supposed to be this: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/gdsTv/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
 var pattern = /(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+)[;]?/i;
 var res = pattern.exec(startVals); //res is now an array with each match

 leftSlider.end.x = parseInt(res[1], 10);
 leftSlider.end.y = parseInt(res[2], 10);
 rightSlider.end.x = parseInt(res[3], 10);
 rightSlider.end.y = parseInt(res[4], 10);
 topSlider.end.x = parseInt(res[5], 10);
 topSlider.end.y = parseInt(res[6], 10);
```

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without a radix.  `parseInt("010") === 8` on most interpreters, but not all since [Annex E](http://es5.github.com/#E) says "15.1.2.2: The specification of the function parseInt no longer allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character as octal values."

Comment: Good to know.  I've been humming along for years assuming 10 was the hard and fast default.  Above code edited.

Comment: I'd be glad to see that "feature" die a cold, hard death.  As a programmer, I know when I'm passing octal or hex into parseInt and will tell it such.

Comment: if you hum along for a few more years and don't care about legacy interpreters, it will be.